# if JavaScript string starts with hyphen then count occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Basically I have an array of strings like this:

```
var array = [
    'Top level',
    '- Sub item',
    '-- Child of sub',
    'Another top',
    'Yet another top',
    '- Child',
];
```

I'm trying to loop each string and check if the string starts with a hyphen, if so count how many times and then remove.

I can do it kind of like this:

```
if (string.substring(0, 1) == "-") {
    // ...
} else if (string.substring(0, 2) == "--") {
    // ...
} else if (string.substring(0, 3) == "---") {
    // ...
}
```

I haven't tested but you can get the idea..

I'm hoping for an easier solution maybe with a regex? Any help?

Thanks.

**-- EDIT --**

I need to count and remove the hyphens from each string because I have a text area for a user to enter a string with new lines and hyphens.

Textarea value:

```
Top level
- Sub item
-- Child of sub
Another top
Yet another top
- Child
```

I am then exploding the textarea value into an array:

```
var array = textareaValue.split('\n');

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var this = array[i];
    // Now check for hyphens and count how many
    // if (hyphens === '-')
    // else if (hyphens === '--') ...etc
};
```

Comment: And then remove what?

Comment: This doesn't work all element with '-' go to match with the first ;)

Comment: Sorry and then remove the hyphens from the string

Comment: Both, I'm going to edit my question to include more information

Comment: What is the actual end result? A list or dropdown? It sounds like an X/Y problem as it stands

Comment: @mplungjan - seems like trying creating tree or menu

Comment: @LeviCole, so why you need count?

Comment: The end result is to create a folder structure from the textarea value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're already looping through to get 'string' (I've used 'val' below to remove possible confusion with 'string' type in other languages)

```
val = val.replace(/^-+/, '')
```

Edit: tested and there's no need to escape the '-' in this usage

Explanation:

- .replace is a method of all strings
- using // allows a regex
- ^ start of line
- '-' literal
- '+' one or more

Update: to include get the count, you can do:

```
var matches = val.match("^(-+).*");
length = matches == null ? 0 : matches[1].length;
```

- match is a method of all strings
- '^' match start
- '(' ')' applies a group, which is returned in the second value of matches, ie the  [1]
- ?: used because if there's no match, then matches will be null

Update to match question's edit:

```
var array = textareaValue.split('\n');

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var thisValue = array[i];
    // Now check for hyphens and count how many
    var matches = thisValue.match("^(-+).*");
    var hyphenCount = matches == null ? 0 : matches[1].length;
    var fixedValue = thisValue.replace(/^-+/, '')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = [];
array = array.map(function(str) {
    var match = str.match(/^(-*) ?/);
    count.push(match[1].length);
    return str.substr(match[0].length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count matches (i.e. how many hyphens) with a **regular expression**, and then replace them using the same RegEx matches.

More info on regular expressions and JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map over the strings, using a regular expression to match (and implicitly count) the hyphens and attaching the remainder of each string.

```js
var array = [
  'Top level',
  '- Sub item',
  '-- Child of sub',
  'Another top',
  'Yet another top',
  '- Child',
];

function countCharacter(data, char) {
  var rex = /^(-*)(.*)$/; // hyphens in first group, body in second
  return data.map(function(it) {
    var res = it.match(rex);
    console.log(res);
    return {
      count: res[1].length,
      text: res[2]
    };
  });
}

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(countCharacter(array, '-'));
```

```html
<pre id=r></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [replace with function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

```
array.map(function(v){
    var s,vv=0;
    s = v.replace(/^-+/,function(p1){
     vv = p1.length;
     return '';
}) 
    return {
        s:s, v:vv
    }
});
```

```js
var array = [
    'Top level',
    '- Sub item',
    '-- Child of sub',
    'Another top',
    'Yet another top',
    '- Child',
];    
var mapped = array.map(function(v){
        var s,vv=0;
        s = v.replace(/^-+/,function(p1){
         vv = p1.length;
         return '';
    }) 
        return {
            name:s, count:vv
        }
    });
  
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(mapped, null,2);
```

```html
<pre id='res'></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get count and replacement in **single match invocation**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var elem = array[i];
    var m = (elem.match(/^(-+)(.*)$/) || ['', elem]);
    var count = m[1].length;
    var replaced = m[2];
};
```

If an element doesn't have `-` at start then above code will get `count=0` and `replaced` same as original string.